# Create an error popup message using python Dash

Tags: python, plotly

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to download data using Dash:

"ValueError: [E088] Text of length 2479607 exceeds maximum of 2100000. The parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too long by checking `len(text)`"

Rather than fix the error, I find it sufficient to just display a popup message when this occurs. Any advice would be helpful here. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear where the error message is and where your comment is. Please try to separate between the two.

Comment: @Hazmah, thanks for the input. I've just added space between my comments and the error I'm seeing

Comment: So, you built a dashboard by dash containing a download button and when the user clicks on this button to download a file, he/she probably gets this error and you decided to pop up this error, right? Because you didn't explain the problem very well.

Comment: @Hazmah, correct. I created a dashboard and when the user clicks a button to download the data, they receive the error message above. Rather than this error message, I would like to create my own popup that is displayed rather than the error.

Comment: This message only pops up when the size of the file is very large, right?

Comment: @Hazmah, That's correct. And like I said, I don't need to fix the error necessarily. I would just like to create a popup when this error occurs. Essentially I just need advice on creating a popup using dash

Comment: @Hazmah, I have found something called dash bootstrap alerts. Do you think this could be a solution for my issue?

Comment: That's great, how do you think you can use it?